# Android appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01 Preview don't work

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0, preview

I used this code:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/jsoup-1.11.3.jar')
}
```

But preview dose not work.

[image]

I'm talking about in Android Studio. When I use my phone it was working.

Comment: clean build, rebuild, also try selecting a different device.

Comment: can you post exception trace from `Logcat`

Comment: I had the same problem. Didn't find solution yet

Comment: I find it now...

Comment: Have you solved the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Check this image.
Problem solved to select the 'Light'

[image]

Comment: Your preview will not be accurate without the AppCompat theme.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Show issues on Preview Screen fix that and refresh once...

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1
```